# How to read in username/password from ".my.cnf" in Ruby MySQL driver?

Tags: mysql, ruby

Is there a way to connect to the MySQL server using the mysql gem without passing a username/pwd combo and instead loading it from the .my.cnf file?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to load them is using `inifile` gem.

```
require 'inifile'
client_options_hash = IniFile.new('~/.my.cnf')['client']
```

Then you can just use the values from `client_options_hash` to set up your connection.